# How to set radio register of cc2500 and cc2511 to maximum data rate (500 Kbps)?

Tags: rf, communication

-I am using cc2500 at target device and cc2511 at Host device.

-I want to transmit and receive data between this two device at 500 Kbps data rates.

-My X'tal freq for cc2500 is 27MHz  and for cc2511 is 48 MHz.

-My base freq is 2410 MHz.

-I tried automatically generated register setting from smart RF studio but it's not working.

-I know that below register are affected for changing data rate .

**MDMCFG4,MDMCFG3,,MDMCFG2,MDMCFG1,MDMCFG0,DEVIATN,FSCAL3,FSCAL2,FSCAL1,FSCAL0,PKTCTRL**

-I tried as much as i possible but failed to communicate this two device.

help me to figure out this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Does your hardware works with a lower data rate?
Can you connect the two units with a coax cable and two 10dB attenuators (One on each unit) and verify a link at 500kbps? 
Do you get CRC or framing errors from the devices? 
Do you have a wifi network on channel 1, bluetooth tranceiver, other 2.4GHz devices near your units?

Edit: Did you check the crystals? They should be within 80ppm of each other. For 2 nodes with 27MHz crystals of the CC2500 it means a maximum of 200Hz difference between the 2 units. The CC25xx requires a maximum 40ppm error from its timing source (Crystal or oscillator). Try generating a CW signal and measure the difference with a spectrum analyzer.

To make measurement of the crystal easier, you can output its frequency/192 to GDO0.

Comment: :Yes,My hardware works with lower data rates.I want to simple connect this two chip for data transfer.At lower data rates there are no kind of error during communication.

Comment: Next step in the debugging process then..